# install zeppelin with spark in docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-spark, docker-compose, apache-zeppelin

I was trying to install zeppelin as shown in [this](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-zeppelin/blob/master/zeppelin/Dockerfile) dockerfile, but with a different version of spark and hadoop (see [this](https://github.com/kevinsuedmersen/hadoop-sandbox/blob/kevinsuedmersen/zeppelin/Dockerfile) dockerfile in my repo for more details). However, I am getting the following error log when running `apt-get update`:

```
Step 5/10 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 1ee84513acc7
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release.gpg
Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports Release
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [44.9 kB]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [16.3 kB]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [1652 B]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages [20 B]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [992 kB]
Err http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org jessie Release [77.3 kB]
Get:7 http://deb.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [9098 kB]
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/deb.debian.org_debian_dists_jessie-updates_main_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 20 23046
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 10.2 MB in 1s (7375 kB/s)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
ERROR: Service 'zeppelin' failed to build
```

It seems like this is somehow related to the jessie package. I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508724/failed-to-fetch-jessie-backports-repository) and [this](https://www.lucas-nussbaum.net/blog/?p=947) article and I tried including

```
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie.list
RUN echo "deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
RUN sed -i '/deb http:\/\/deb.debian.org\/debian jessie-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

script before the `apt-get update` command in the dockerfile of my repo, but still without success.